# Getting Heartrate from Samsung Health SDK for Wearable

Tags: java, android, samsung

I'm currently trying to get access of the Heartrate-Sensor of my Samsung Galaxy Watch 4 Classic inside Android Studio to display it inside a TextView.

Therefore I've been reading myself into the Samsung Health SDK for quite awhile now, but it seems like it's still not working.

At my latest try I had this Code:

**manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.health.permission.read" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BODY_SENSORS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

**Activity:**

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import com.example.test.databinding.ActivityVitalsBinding;
import com.samsung.android.sdk.healthdata.HealthDataStore;
import com.samsung.android.sdk.healthdata.HealthConstants;
import com.samsung.android.sdk.healthdata.HealthDataResolver;
import com.samsung.android.sdk.healthdata.HealthDataResolver.Filter;
import com.samsung.android.sdk.healthdata.HealthPermissionManager;
import com.samsung.android.sdk.healthdata.HealthResultHolder;
import com.samsung.android.sdk.healthdata.HealthResultHolder.ResultListener;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;


public class VitalsActivity extends Activity {

    private HealthDataStore healthDataStore;
    private ActivityVitalsBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityVitalsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

       healthDataStore = new HealthDataStore(this, new HealthDataStore.ConnectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnected() {
            System.out.println("Connected successfully");
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(HealthConnectionErrorResult healthConnectionErrorResult) {
            System.out.println("couldn't connect");
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected() {

        }
    });
    healthDataStore.connectService();
    }

private void requestHeartRatePermission() {
    HealthPermissionManager.PermissionKey key =
            new HealthPermissionManager.PermissionKey(HealthConstants.HeartRate.HEALTH_DATA_TYPE, HealthPermissionManager.PermissionType.READ);

    HealthPermissionManager permissionManager = new HealthPermissionManager(healthDataStore);

    permissionManager.requestPermissions(new HashSet<HealthPermissionManager.PermissionKey>(Arrays.asList(key)))
            .setResultListener(new ResultListener<HealthPermissionManager.PermissionResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(HealthPermissionManager.PermissionResult result) {
                    if (result.equals(true)) {
                        readHeartRateData();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("access denied");
                    }
                }
            });
}

private void readHeartRateData() {
    HealthDataResolver resolver = new HealthDataResolver(healthDataStore, null);

    HealthDataResolver.ReadRequest request = new HealthDataResolver.ReadRequest.Builder()
            .setDataType(HealthConstants.HeartRate.HEALTH_DATA_TYPE)
            .build();

    resolver.read(request)
            .setResultListener(result -> {
                try (Cursor cursor = result.getResultCursor()) {
                    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        int heartRateIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(HealthConstants.HeartRate.HEART_RATE);
                        if (heartRateIndex != -1) {
                            int heartRate = cursor.getInt(heartRateIndex);
                            System.out.println("current heartrate: " + heartRate);
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("couldn't find heartrate-column");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("error while reading heartrate-data");
                }
            });
}
```

But with this I get the Error:

```
E/HealthDataStore: disconnectService: Context instance is invalid
D/HealthDataStore: Trying to connect with Health Service fails (error code: 2)
D/HealthDataStore: Check SupportedDevice
D/HealthSDK-DeviceUtil: Server URL : https://hub.samsungapps.com/product/appCheck.as?appInfo=com.sec.android.app.shealth@0&deviceId=sdk_gwear_x86&mnc=260&csc=FAIL&openApi=30&mcc=310
D/HealthSDK-DeviceUtil: Downloading Samsung Health is unavailable (0)
```

can you help me out here?